# How to import folder-level shared libraries in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

First my understanding of folder-level shared libraries:
It's a groovy script I can place anywhere in the repository where I want it to use (i.e. where my Jenkinsfile will be).

If this is wrong please let me know.

My question:
How can I include this library. For global libraries I can use `@Library($libraryName)` to import libraries I registered with a name as global library. But for folder-level libraries there is no name specified. How do I import them? Do I really have to specify the git repo like demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47892822/2576531)?

Comment: Your understanding of a folder-level shared library is incorrect. A shared library is (currently) organized in [this directory structure](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#directory-structure) and can be loaded using `@Library` or the other supporting APIs (like `library` step). Maybe you are looking for the `load` step to use scripts in the same repository? It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now I just try to understand what a folder-level-shared library is. From the documentation it's not getting clear to me.
Where do I register this library? Where/When do I use it? How do I use it?

Comment: I hope most of your questions will be answered by [this section of documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#folder-level-shared-libraries).

Comment: Or some of the other parts that show you how to configure and setup the library before using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Folder-level shared libraries work similar to global shared libraries.

They also need a dedicated repository featuring the known layout (`vars`, `src` folders). And you need to load them using `@Library(<name>) _` if you choose not to load implicitly.

Differences are:

- You define the library to use in the settings of a Jenkins folder
- They are not trusted (as written in the link posted in the comments)

Just open the settings of a Jenkins folder and you'll find the options.

Comment: For those not familiar with folders, they can be created in Jenkins by going to "New Item" and selecting "Folder". I guess it's kind of like a View, but allows for an additional level of granularity (including shared libraries).